# javascript extracting floating point numbers regex are not matched properly

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I've below javascript program -

```js
var rx = /^the values should(?: between (\d+(\.\d+)?) and (\d+(\.\d+)?))$/;
var sentence = "the values should between 1.1 and 2.7";
var arr = rx.exec(sentence);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

I want to extract the number 1.1 and 2.7 into into an array from the matched line.

When I run the above program I get the below result

```
["the values should between 1.1 and 2.7","1.1",".1","2.7",".7"]
```

In the above program `1.1` becomes `.1` and `2.7` becomes `.7`.

How can I match it in javascript correctly.

Comment: Your question is how do you form the groups properly. All you need to do is use the non-capturing group syntax `(?:xxx)` for the inner groupings instead of plain capturing group parentheses.

Comment: Example of the fix suggested by Pointy `var rx = /^the values should(?: between (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) and (\d+(?:\.\d+)?))$/;`

Comment: Minor point on English. The input `sentance` reads poorly. Better phrasing includes *"... should lie between ..."* or *"... should be between ..."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pointy* is right in suggesting in his/her comment a better use of non capturing parentheses: `(?: ... )`, to avoid unwanted captures.

I also understand that the first element of your output array is unwanted, so you can use the [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) function to remove it.

Your code could be:

```js
var rx = /^the values should between (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) and (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/;
var sentence = "the values should between 1.1 and 2.7";
var arr = rx.exec(sentence);
arr.shift(); // Remove the first element of the array.
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

**Edit:**
*CAustin* judiciously questionned about the outer non-capturing parentheses in the original regex, which I left in my initial answer. On reflection, they seemed useless to me, so I removed them to simplify the regex.

Comment: What's the purpose of the outer non-capturing group?

Comment: @CAustin, on reflection the outer non-capturing group seems also useless to me. You are right to point this out. I left it because it was in the original regex, but I guess that it can be removed. I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character group `[\d.]` if the float values are expected formatted properly:

```js
var rx = /^the values should between ([\d.]+) and ([\d.]+)$/;
var sentence = "the values should between 1.1 and 2.7";
var [, from, to] = rx.exec(sentence);
console.log(from, to);
```